# testing for instance of a class

Tags: class, boolean, smalltalk, squeak

I have a question in squeak, I'm completely new to it so I'm asking about the basics. I created a class

```
Object subclass: #Course
instanceVariableNames: 'id name day time isTwoHoursLong'
classVariableNames: ''
poolDictionaries: ''
category: 'Kernel-Objects'
```

which implements the following method:

```
isTwoHoursLong: aBoolean
(aBoolean isMemberOf: Boolean) 
    ifFalse: [self error: 'invalid input value']
    ifTrue: [isTwoHoursLong:=aBoolean.].
```

aBoolean has to be true or false (an instance of Boolean).
now I tried using the method:

```
|c1|
c1:=Course new.
c1 isTwoHoursLong:true.
```

but for some reason I fall into the ifFalse option which sends an error.
can someone maybe help clear things up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `isKindOf:` instead of `isMemberOf:`.
`True` and `False` are subclasses of `Boolean` and `isKindOf:` tests whether the argument is the class or a superclass of the receiver.

But I would probably omit this manual typecheck altogether.

Comment: This. Is complete weird for smalltalk to do a type-check to assign a variable.

Comment: but if this specific variable has to hold either true or false, wouldn't I want to check for it?

Comment: No, you shouldn't.
That is defensive programming, and in Smalltalk we don't do that.
Messages are written usually by people, programmers that read your code and understand it If your message begins with is... we all assume it should be a boolean. If something fails, we read it carefully.
Anyway, it is strange to have such a long name for an instance variable.
And also, use is...: to set it, you can do beTwoHoursLong to set it true and #dontBeTwoHoursLong for false. 
Also.. consider having the langth instead of the boolean. Otherwise, courses with 3 or 4 hours are the same

Comment: I agree with @CarlosE.Ferro (except for the bit about long instance variables - don't be afraid to be explicit, _especially_ in Smalltalk). If you're used to a strongly-typed language (e.g. Java), then you're used to the compiler handling this sort of thing for you. Smalltalk is different (some say "dynamically typed") - more trust is placed in the programmer to a) send the correct types to methods, or b) be able to debug it if something unexpected happens (debugging in a "live" language like Smalltalk is much easier than in write-compile-run-cycle-type languages, once you get the hang of it).

Comment: I should've mentioned that this is a hw assignment, and we were asked to return an error in case we get something other that Boolean, which means that I don't really have a choice but to check. the same is for the name, not my choice. sorry for not mentioning that in the begining